# "java.lang.NumberFormatException: null" error in AdapterPost.java

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, adapter

I am getting this error "java.lang.NumberFormatException: null java.lang.Long.parseLong". it's causing the whole social media app to crash.  The whole social media app was working well for a few hours with all the features and adding posts as it should, but all over sudden crashed. The logcat is pointing to the adapter post as the source of error. Using firebase. Please Help!

Below is the code that seems to be a problem

```
    Calendar calendar=Calendar.getInstance(Locale.getDefault());
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(Long.parseLong(pTimeStamp));
    String pTime= DateFormat.format("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm aa",calendar).toString();
```

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Comment: Please do not post pictures of code. Copy code from your editor and paste it into your question. You're also going to want to run your debugger. If you don't know how to use one, now is a good time to learn.

Comment: `getPTime()` returned null... Why not just make that method return a `long` itself?

Comment: I've only been doing android for the last 4 weeks. How do I rewrite code  to return a long?